# Ruby FileUtils.mkdir_p is only creating parent directories

Tags: ruby, fileutils

I have a controller in Rails, with an action that is meant to create a new directory.

This action should create the directory "/public/graph_templates/aaa/test". However, it leaves off the final directory "test". Why is this only creating parent directories?

```
  def create_temporary_template
    dir = File.dirname("#{Rails.root}/public/graph_templates/aaa/test")
    FileUtils.mkdir_p dir
  end
```

Docs: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you use `dir = File.dirname("#{Rails.root}/public/graph_templates/aaa/test")`,

then the `dir` is `"#{Rails.root}/public/graph_templates/aaa"`.

You could just pass the path to `FileUtils.mkdir_p`.

```
  def create_temporary_template
    dir = "#{Rails.root}/public/graph_templates/aaa/test"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p dir
  end
```

Comment: yep just logged and noticed this, thanks! Is this actually treating "test" as a file?

Comment: @DonnyP No, "test" is the directory name.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your use of `dirname`:

```
File.dirname("/foo/bar")
# => "/foo"
```

`dirname` removes the last entry from the path. Per [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-dirname):

> Returns all components of the filename given in file_name except the last one.

Usually that's the correct thing if your path contains a directory, or directory hierarchy, with the filename:

```
File.dirname("/foo/bar/baz.txt")
# => "/foo/bar"
```

But, in this case it's chopping off your desired trailing directory.

I'd recommend taking a look at the [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) class that is included in Ruby's Standard Library. It wraps File, Dir, FileUtils, FileTest, and probably a Swiss-Army knife and kitchen sink into one class, making it very convenient to work on files and directories with one class.

```
require 'pathname'
dir = Pathname.new("/foo/bar/baz.txt")
# => "/foo/bar"

dir.mkpath # would create the path
```

I've found Pathname to be very useful, though it's still young.